# How to skip stream filter if filtered value is null?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of Java objects. In database some of objects has got field `nextSyncDate` and some not. What I want to do is to **put filter** on java stream but **only if** this field exists and is for example greater than today date. So simplify, I want to get objects which `nextSyncDate` is greater than today and objects which hasn't got this field (getting NullPointException after `get()` on this field).

I have tried something like this but it's not working like I want to..

```java
List<MyObjects> objects;
objects.stream()
    .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getNextSyncDate()) && obj.getNextSyncDate().before(new Date()))
```

On the other hand, all objects has got field `counter`. What I want to do additionally is to set `nextSyncDate` (for example for tomorrow) for every object which `counter` is greater than 15. I tried to `.map()` objects before `.filter()` but it's also not working.

Comment: Try tto avoid mutating the objects while using streams. Apart from which the `MyObjects` definition is not really clear in terms of updating the `nextSyncDate` based on the `counter`. (`map`ping to the same object shall work as well, maybe just have a utility for that) But that attempt is not visible in the question.

Comment: You want to reject items having a date which is greater than today, in other words, you want accept them when their field is null or earlier, so you have to use `.filter(obj -> obj.getNextSyncDate() == null || obj.getNextSyncDate().before(new Date()))`, i.e. use the logical or `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a stream, you are not directly modifying its source. You need to collect the data. Your filter seems to work as intended. I would personally not recommend having a filtered stream with side effects (do your "`counter` > 15 then set `nextSyncDate`" logic somewhere else) but you could do it with another stream operation such as `peek` (`map` is for transformation which isn't necessary in your case but could be used):

```
List<MyObjects> objects = /* omitted */;
List<MyObjects> filteredObjects = objects.stream()
    .peek(MyObjects::setNextSycDateWithSomeLogic())
    .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getNextSyncDate()) && obj.getNextSyncDate().before(new Date()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter can include the `counter` requirement as well:

```
    final Date TODAY = Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    final int COUNTER_THRESHOLD = 15;
    objects.stream()
            .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getNextSyncDate())
                    && obj.getNextSyncDate().before(TODAY)
                    && obj.getCounter() > COUNTER_THRESHOLD)
```

The intermediate stream provided by the filter has the objects which need to be updated, so a forEach can be applied:

```
    final Date TODAY = Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    final Date TOMORROW = Date.from(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    final int COUNTER_THRESHOLD = 15;
    objects.stream()
            .filter(obj -> Objects.nonNull(obj.getNextSyncDate())
                    && obj.getNextSyncDate().before(TODAY)
                    && obj.getCounter() > COUNTER_THRESHOLD)
            .forEach(obj -> obj.setNextSyncDate(TOMORROW));
```

Also, consider using LocalDate instead of deprecated Date.